# Named Colors from pod only use light appearance instead of dark

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, ios13

I have a private pod and within it is my asset catalog. There's a named color with "Any Appearance" and "Dark Appearance" values set. In my main project that's consuming the pod, I can set the color[image: storyboard color selection]

It even looks correct in the storyboard when I switch the interface styles between dark and light. The issue is when I then run the code, it only uses the light appearance, even in dark mode. To make it more confusing, if I set the color via code, e.g., `viewDidLoad` it works as expected.

```swift
let bundle = Bundle(for: PrivatePodClass.self)
let color = UIColor(named: "tableViewSectionHeader", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
// Works
view.backgroundColor = color
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with XCode 11 or if it's something with cocoapods, but I'd like to not be forced to set the colors via code if I don't have to.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `traitCollection` in the `compatibleWith:` parameter? I think the colors that update accordingly to the traitcollection's appearance are UIDynamicColor (or something like that). So maybe if you don't pass a traitcollection, it just uses the standard appearance

Comment: That wouldn't affect the main issue which is setting the color via the storyboard (from another pod) is never using the dark appearance. Setting it via code works fine though. When setting the interface style in the storyboard to dark, it looks like it would be correct but it never actually renders that way at runtime.

Comment: Check if you are overriding this value is another place. if that's not the case maybe share the pod so we try it and post the code that works

Comment: I made a sample project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/Bendetta/AssetCatalogBug  -- Open up app/ColorAssetBug and you can see what I mean

Comment: Did you ever create a bug or find a workaround for this, other than programmatically setting the color or copying the asset lib to your main project?

Comment: I think that the storyboard can only read assets from the same bundle.  So you can put the storyboard in the same framework bundle as the assets, or put the assets in the main bundle where the storyboard is.   You can get a storyboard from a bundle with storyboardWithName:bundle:

Comment: @Ben Did you finally find any solution?

Comment: @AlexandreNussbaumer I did not. I left that project shortly after posting this question though, so I can't say I've looked into it extensively since.

Answer (score 0):

```
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "redColor", in: nibBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Replace `bundle` with `nibBundle`. It worked for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x92tF.png)

Comment: The issue was (is? haven't tried messing with this problem in awhile) that the colors don't work when setting through the storyboard. There were no issues when setting it via code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually located in the modules.
If your `Colors.sassets` file (where the named colors are defined) is not located in the main module it won't work at runtime.

The current workaround could be to copy your assets file from your external module to the main module with a script in a build phase.

I found the solution there and you'll find additional information about it: https://github.com/lechuckcaptain/TestResourcesIntoModule